# SWF file loading Error #2036 only few times

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have used the following code:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader;
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityError);
var swfUrl:String = "content/1-1-1.swf";
loader.load(new URLRequest(swfUrl));
this.addChild(loader);
function onLoadComplete(e:Event){
    trace("swf loaded successfully");
}
function securityError(e:SecurityErrorEvent){
    trace(swfUrl + " security issue." + e.text);
}
function ioError(e:IOErrorEvent){
    var errorMsg:String = swfUrl + " not found." + e.text;
    trace(errorMsg);
    ExternalInterface.call("ErrorTracker", errorMsg);
    // ErrorTracker sendimg for tracking that function I writeen in html page
    // This error getting very few times not for all times.
    // Getting mails with this message as: content/1-1-1.swf not found.Error #2036
}
```

All most every times it's running fine. Only very few time, I am getting Error #2036. And mostly this error comes with Window7 or Windows8.

It would be great help if any one can found out some reason why adobe flash player not not loading SWF file some times while the file is available on the same server.

Thanks,
Uday